# How to rotate a bytearray key in python without converting it's elements to an int first?

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, bit-shift

I'm trying to implement a key schedule function that can be used as as DES- round key. so the key schedule function I wrote is supposed to take input as 8-bytes bytearray and rotate it(not shift) specific number of bit. But can't see how to implement it as convering the byte array to an int will cause an error sooner or later. what I tried is:

```py
def key_sckedule(key: bytearray):
    """
    A function that takes a key as bytes input and use a permutation to mutate the key and return a
    mutated key that can act as be used as a sub key for a DES-round. The permutation is right rotation by
    1-Bit for round 1, 2, 9, 16 and 2-Bits for all other rounds.

    :param key: a bytes object representing the key use minimum key size of 8-bytes (64-Bit).
    :return: The round key
    """
    if len(key) < 8:
        raise ValueError("Size is less than 8-Bytes")

    global __round_number
    if __round_number in [1, 2, 9, 16]:
        shift_value = 1
    else:
        shift_value = 2

    key_to_int = int(key)
    key_to_int = key_to_int >> shift_value
    __round_number += 1

    print(key_to_int)
    return bytearray(key_to_int.to_bytes(8, byteorder="little"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a byte array to an integer, use:

```
int(b.hex(), 16)
```

To go in the other direction, use:

```
value.to_bytes(length, 'big')
```

where length is the length of your original byte array.

Note that when you rotate by k bits, you need to shift the bottom k bits left by `total_length_in_bits - k`, and or that with the original value shifted right by `k` bits

Comment: thank's alot it worked now but can you better explain why converting ```bytearray``` to hex works even if Key has non hex bytes like```K``` and not  works with ```int``` function directly, and what do you mean with shift bottom k bits as I can't understand.

Comment: You're doing a rotation.  If you're rotating "right" by 2, and you have, let's say 64 bits, then bits 2-63 need to move to bits 0-61, and bits 0 and 1 need to move up to bits 62 and 63